# Como achar um texto dentro de um arquivo com Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Bom dia

Eu preciso criar um script para normalizar alguns arquivos do tipo DFM (arquivo de formulário do Delphi) onde eu preciso trocar a expressão o texto CommandText para SQL.Text e o que tiver após o = fique ()

```
  object QrUsuario: TSQLDataSet
    CommandText = 
      'select USUARIO_ATIVO, USUARIO_NOME, fdsafdsa143 34112 USUARIO_SENHA from TABELA_US' +
      'UARIO'
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <>
    SQLConnection = DbDados
    Left = 451
    Top = 80
  end
```

O problema acontece quando tem quebra de linha como no exemplo acima. Se tiver na mesma linha funcionava ao usar o script:

```
(CommandText) += ('.+')
```

Mas não é encontrado a quebra.

Para delimitar o texto tem que começar e terminar com '
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Eu tentei usar essa expressão também, mas aí ela não para:

```
(CommandText) += \s*('[\s\r\n\w\+\'\"\#\!\@\$\%\&\*\(\)\_\-\=\[\]\{\}\?\;\:\.\,\\\|\<\>\/]+')
```

Answer (score 0):

O comando que funcionou foi este:

```
CommandText = ((\s*'.*'|\s+\+)*)
```

Ele resultou no matchabaixo:

```
CommandText = 'select USUARIO_ATIVO, USUARIO_NOME, USUARIO_SENHA from TABELA_US' + 
              'UARIO'
```

Com o grupo 1 com o valor:

```
  'select USUARIO_ATIVO, USUARIO_NOME, USUARIO_SENHA from TABELA_US' +
  'UARIO'
```